# Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm having problems with Android Google Places API - auto complete feature.

I'm trying to use [Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi?hl=zh-tw#getAutocompletePredictions(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter)) method to get the placeId, however, it doesn't work.(The output doesn't even show "can't get the value")
Could anyone help me?

Here is my Java code:

```
 PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> result =
            Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, query,
                    mLatLonBounds, null);

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<AutocompletePredictionBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions) {

            if (autocompletePredictions.getStatus().isSuccess()) { //如果回傳SUCCESS

                Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
                resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                    resultList.add(prediction.getPlaceId().toString());
                }
            }
           else {
                resultList.add("can't get the vaule");
            }
            autocompletePredictions.release();
        }

    });

 textView.setText(resultList.get(0).toString());
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you enable Google Places API for Android in developers console?

Comment: Yes I did, the page of Google Places API For Android has been successfully  received  the request when I run the project,  but it is still not working. @rafsanahmad007

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I got it worked by following the below steps

- Enable the Google Places API for Android in developers console and
  check on the credentials page that your key is still present.
- Add the required library to your module (play-services-places:11.2.0+).
- Use the below code to get the predictions

  ```
  Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> results = mGeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(yourInputString, yourLatLngBounds, yourTypeFilter);
  ```
- Add on success listener for the predictions as below

  ```
  results.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse>() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse autocompletePredictions) {
      Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
      suggesstions = new ArrayList<String>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
      if (iterator.hasNext()) {
          while (iterator.hasNext()) {
              AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
              //do your stuff with prediction here
          }
      }else {
        //Nothing matches...
      }
      autocompletePredictions.release();
  }
  });
  ```
- Add on failure listener for the predictions as below

  ```
  results.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Error while fetching suggessions : "+e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

  });
  ```

  **If all the above code snippet is placed properly, then you probably check your internet connectivity.**

Hope the above code will be helpful.

Thanks.